# Is it possible to invoke SOAP request in JavaFX?

Tags: soap, javafx

I've been spending considerable time on this, while finally realized that most articles are teaching how to access RESTful web services but not SOAP.

Is this possible? I mean can I write my own clients codes to invoke SOAP request to remote web server?

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful:

http://abhisarswami.blogspot.com/2009/05/soap-request-from-javafx.html